# Elassandra troubling while installation

Tags: python, elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

I have use the Tar method for installing Elassandra.

after typing the command : `python pylib/setup.py install`
I am getting the following error and do not know how to resolve it:

```
aims@aims:~/elassandra$ sudo python pylib/setup.py install
[sudo] password for aims: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pylib/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    ext_modules=get_extensions(),
  File "pylib/setup.py", line 27, in get_extensions
    return cythonize("cqlshlib/copyutil.py")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.25.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 818, in cythonize
    aliases=aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.25.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 704, in create_extension_list
    for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.25.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 108, in nonempty
    raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: 'cqlshlib/copyutil.py' doesn't match any files
```

Kindly, help me how I can resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to be in the `pylib` directory

do this instead `cd pylib && python setup.py install`

Comment: No it didn't solve my issue. thank you for your attempt.